# Play and pause audio onclick by js library

Tags: javascript, html, audio

How can i play audio on my web (even for mobile) by Java script but just put Js code one times in .tpl file. I use NukeViet CMS, if i use the code below for each audio my web will hardly load.

```js
var audioTagged = document.getElementById('audioID');
    audioTagged.src = 'http://tienganhphothong.tienganh123.com/file/phothong/lop8/bai1/vocabulary/straight.mp3';
    audioTagged.load();
```

```html
<p onclick="triggerAudio()"><img src="http://caicay.vn/uploads/news/loa.gif" /></p>
```

I want to put js code one times in `header` tag and for each audio i just insert code like this `<span class="uba_audioButton" media-url="http://tienganhphothong.tienganh123.com/file/phothong/lop8/bai1/vocabulary/straight.mp3"></span>` in editor.

I want to play audio code like http://www.tienganh123.com/tieng-anh-pho-thong-lop-8-bai-1/2604-vocabulary.html , the image hasn't to change when clicking on the bottom, just simply click-play then click-pause.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Audio` class of JavaScript.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/ks26c6qm/).

Here is the snippet.

```js
function triggerAudio() {
  var file = new Audio('http://tienganhphothong.tienganh123.com/file/phothong/lop8/bai1/vocabulary/straight.mp3');
  file.play();
}
```

```html
<p onclick="triggerAudio()">
  <img src="http://caicay.vn/uploads/news/loa.gif" />
</p>
```

**According to the requirement mentioned in the comments by the OP, this might solve the problem.**

Check out this **updated** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/ks26c6qm/1/).

Here is the snippet.

```js
function triggerAudio(abc) {
  var playid = abc.id.substring(4);
  document.getElementById("audio" + playid).play();
}
```

```css
audio {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p id="play1" onclick="triggerAudio(this)">
  <img src="http://caicay.vn/uploads/news/loa.gif" />AFFECT</p>
<p id="play2" onclick="triggerAudio(this)">
  <img src="http://caicay.vn/uploads/news/loa.gif" />ANNOY</p>
<p id="play3" onclick="triggerAudio(this)">
  <img src="http://caicay.vn/uploads/news/loa.gif" />BALD</p>
<p id="play4" onclick="triggerAudio(this)">
  <img src="http://caicay.vn/uploads/news/loa.gif" />BLOND</p>
<p id="play5" onclick="triggerAudio(this)">
  <img src="http://caicay.vn/uploads/news/loa.gif" />CHARACTER</p>

<audio id="audio1">
  <source src="http://tienganhphothong.tienganh123.com/file/phothong/lop8/bai1/vocabulary/affect.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
<audio id="audio2">
  <source src="http://tienganhphothong.tienganh123.com/file/phothong/lop8/bai1/vocabulary/annoy.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
<audio id="audio3">
  <source src="http://tienganhphothong.tienganh123.com/file/phothong/lop8/bai1/vocabulary/bald.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
<audio id="audio4">
  <source src="http://tienganhphothong.tienganh123.com/file/phothong/lop8/bai1/vocabulary/blond.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
<audio id="audio5">
  <source src="http://tienganhphothong.tienganh123.com/file/phothong/lop8/bai1/vocabulary/character.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

This solution contains very little `Javascript` which you don't need to write separately for every audio you want to play.

Add as much `<audio>` you need in the `HTML` part and this will still work for you.

---

If the **CMS** you are using do not allow `onclick` trigger, then you can register `event listeners` using `javascript`.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        triggerAudio(this);
    });
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/ks26c6qm/2/) with event listeners registered using `javascript`.

Comment: The CMS which i am using can't put js code in editor so if i have js i have to put it in header tag in .tpl file. If i have 1000 mp3 file i have to put 1000 code like this in header tag, it will affect to loading my web. How can i just need to put js code one times ( none mp3 link in js code) , mp3 link will put in editor.
Sorry for my bad English, pleas try to understand me.

Comment: Added another approach. This might solve your problem.

Comment: Is there another resolution? In CMS i am using dosen't allow onclick=trigger, after save article the system automaticly eleminate onclick=trigger just <p... left.

Comment: @LêTrung, Your **CMS** is good. It is **BAD** practice to use inline event listeners. You should use javascript event listeners. I have updated the answer.